# How can somebody perform a grab and throw (person)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Reading the online description for [fire giants](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aFire_Giant), you read that

> They are also fond of grabbing smaller opponents and tossing them somewhere very hot.

I always imagined larger creatures to do that. A giant grabbing and throwing a halfling in lava, an ogre throwing a gnome away annoyed by its pick etc etc. But is there actually a valid 3.5 mechanic to do that? The only thing that comes to mind is the dragon's snatch ability and nothing feat-like. Please enlighten, so my PCs can be used for baseball between a clan of fire giants!

Comment: Pathfinder's Bull Rush maneuver can be used for that, since it allows you to move a creature for several squares without moving with him. 3.5's Bull Rush is a poor and stunted creature, though, so it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Fling Enemy feat from Races of Stone (page 140). The basic function of the feat:

> **Benefit:** When you're grappling a foe, you can fling that foe away from you with a successful Grapple check.

Fire Giants qualify for the feat straight out of the box.

Additionally, the Tome of Battle has a line of maneuvers that enable throwing an enemy. These are Mighty Throw (Setting Sun 1), Devastating Throw (Setting Sun 3), Comet Throw (Setting Sun 4), Soaring Throw (Setting Sun 5), Ballista Throw (Setting Sun 6) and Tornado Throw (Setting Sun 9). They are based on trip mechanics rather than grapple, but the result is the same.